# What is the minimum number of function calls required to find the answer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> There are $11$ balls in the bag. $9$ of them are white, the other $2$ are black. There is a function that returns $true$ if there is at least one black ball in a particular group and $false$ if all of the balls in this group are white. (However, this function doesn't tell us the exact number of black balls in this group)

**Question:**
How many times should we call this function to know exactly which balls are black?

**My attempt:**

Suppose $k$ is the answer. Then it is obvious that $1\leqslant k\leqslant 11$.
Also, if we check first ten balls, then we will know exactly the color of the eleventh ball (since we know from the beginning that there are exactly $2$ black balls in the bag). So, $k\leqslant 10$.
Then I used the following logic: let's divide the initial group of $11$ balls into $3$ groups with $4$, $4$ and $3$ balls in each group respectively. Then divide the latter groups into other $2$ groups each, and so on. Eventually, I found that $k\leqslant 7$. And the answer is $7$. I am not sure, though.

Could someone help me find a stricter solution? Or at least check my answer? I would be very grateful.